how to make openresty support pdf partial download
I am using react pdf 9.1.0 to show the pdf in browser, now I want to make the react pdf support the partial download. The server side was using openresty, I read the pdf.js manual that told me to make the server side add partial download. how to make openresty support the pdf partial download? I have added the configuration:
location /tex/static/proj {
    alias /data/k8s/reddwarf-pro/texhub-server-service/project/;
    add_header Accept-Ranges bytes;
    autoindex off;
}

how to make the openresty handle the pdf range request?
